# Laravel framework plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, laravel

Sorry to open this post again. I want to debug Laravel code in Eclipse. Does Laravel has plugin for Eclipse? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is XDebug, which debugs any PHP code.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug

Comment: Thanks. But the class of Laravel framework cannot run in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just include these two files in `index.php` in the Laravel installation directory:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

then the app can run.

```
$app->run();
```